# Uniformly continuous function in any segment of interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is *uniformly* continuous at any interval $[c,d]$ where $a<c<d<b$. It is true that $f$ is uniformly continuous at $(a,b)$?

How to prove or refute this claim strictly?

Comment: $[c,d]$ is compact so any continuous function will automatically be uniformly continuous on that interval. Hopefully you can see how to get counter-examples then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false, uniform continuity implies, that there exists a continuous extension, so $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}; \ x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ will be a counterexample. 
Furthermore every continuous function is uniformly continuous on a compact set, so you have no non trivial assumption.